# Definition: product $\alpha \cdot f $ with $ f \in \operatorname{Hom}_K(E,F)$ , $\alpha \in K$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I need the definition of product $ \alpha \cdot f $ with $ f \in \operatorname{Hom}_K(E,F), \alpha \in K $.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. In this case $E$ and $ F $ are vector spaces on $K$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f:E\to F$ is a linear transformation with $E,F$ vector space, then $\alpha\cdot f$ is the linear transformation obtained by mapping each $x\in E$ to $\alpha\cdot f(x)\in F$, where $\cdot$ is the action of $K$ on $F$, or scalar multiplication in $F$. Remember for each $x\in E$; $f(x)=y$ is a vector in $F$, so it makes sense to talk about the scalar product $\alpha y$.

In particular, for any pair of $K$ vector spaces $E\to F$ we can make ${\rm Hom}_K(E,F)$ into a vector space by defining the sum of two linear transformations and the scalar product of $\alpha \in K$ and a linear transformation as follows:

$$\begin{align}(1)\hspace{1cm} (f+g)(x):=&f(x)+g(x)\\
(2)\hspace{1cm} (\alpha\cdot  f)(x):=&\alpha \cdot f(x)\end{align}$$

where $+$ and $\cdot$ on the **left** are the new sum and product, and $+$,$\cdot$ on the **right** is the usual sum in $F$.

You can check all axioms with these definitions to see that ${\rm Hom}_K(E,F)$ will obtain a $K$-vector space structure. Moreover, if $E$ and $F$ are of finite dimension, $n$ and $m$ respectively, this space ends up being isomorphic to $K^{m\times n}$.

Comment: ok.. thank you soo much!!

Comment: but sum of two linear transformations and the scalar product of $ a \in K $ are binary function form $E $ in $F$, it is more formal to proof that they are linear trasformations, it is correct?

Comment: Well, the proof is not that hard. If $f,g$ are linear transformatoins $$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$$  $$g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$$ Sum that up, to get $(f+g)(x+y)=(f+g)(x)+(f+g)(y)$, and the same for $\lambda \cdot (f+g)$.

Comment: ok.. of course therefore we have proof that $(f+g),\alpha \cdot f \in \operatorname{Hom}_K(E,F)$ ... then $\operatorname{Hom}_K(E,F)$  has closure under an operations $(f+g),\alpha \cdot f$, is it correct?